# What is the caffeine content in Lavazza brand coffee

Tags: health, caffeine

What is the caffeine content of the Italian coffee LAVAZZA brand?  It is sold at several roast levels, so there is probably some variation.

Answer (score 3):

It is more or less impossible to be precise about this.  The factors involved with dictating caffeine levels of any given coffee bean are numerous, and impossible to define for a single bag of roasted coffee.  Here is Lavazza's answer to your question:

Espresso or mocha coffee 40-80 mg per cup. American coffee 115-120 mg per cup. Instant coffee 65-100 mg per cup. Decaffeinated coffee < 5 mg per cup.

[Lavazza Coffee Welness](http://www.lavazza.us/us/coffee-expertise/training-center/history_coffee/coffee_welness/)